# Building Android default email client: No default.properties exists? (Also, build path errors)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source

I'm just trying to build the default Android email client, the source is located here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email

I cloned the git repository, imported it into Eclipse, but Eclipse groans that default.properties doesn't exist. How do I generate default.properties and fix the build paths for this particular application?

EDIT: I hope I don't sound too demanding here, but there might be some *special* requirement for this particular application, since I've cloned so many other applications and built them successfully, so before replying if you could clone this repo and try building it yourself, that would be swell.

EDIT2: I also tried running this:

```
android update project -p . -t 3 -s
```

in the project directory, which generated the missing files, but now the project inside Eclipse is riddled with hundreds of errors:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbiCp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to import an existing project. Maybe try creating project from source, i.e. create a new android project and specify the location of the source. Eclipse will then create all the necessary files for you, including default.properties.

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting another 'invalid description' error with that, screenshot attached.

http://cl.ly/7kQl

Comment: "Email overlaps the location of another project" probably means you have more than one project already set up in the same folder.

Comment: did you find the answer to this?  I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This file is auto-generated, so you shouldn't have to create it yourself (and if you do, it might get overwritten anyway). Try setting the android library to make eclipse rebuild your project.
This is located at "Project Root->properties->Android.
See which android version is being used and change it to a new one. Then change it back after eclipse has re-build the project for you.

Comment: I tried doing that too, but nothing seems to give. This error is persistent.